# Flutter google play problema con publicación QUERY_ALL_Packages

Tags: flutter, google-play, android-permissions

Buen día
Estoy intentando lanzar actualización de mi app en play store pero a partir del 20 Julio 2022, hay cambiado politicas y me dicen que debo justificar uso de permiso QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES.
Pero yo no tengo declarado ese permiso, he revisado y no encuentro incluso me ponen esto:

```
Permisos android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES
```

uso estos paquetes

```
  file_picker: ^4.5.1
  path_provider: ^2.0.10
  xml: ^6.0.1
  url_launcher: ^6.1.2
  intl: ^0.17.0
  external_app_launcher: ^3.0.0
  receive_sharing_intent: ^1.4.5
  flutter_bloc: ^8.0.1
  equatable: ^2.0.3
```

y mi manifiesto en android/app/src/main/AndroidManifiest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.firu.firu_reader">
   <application
        android:label="Firu"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Add the openShared 

            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            -->


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>


 
            <!-- end the openShared -->


        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

</manifest>
```

Uso el intent-filter para ayudar a la importación de archivo que recibe gracias a la funcion compartir de otras app.
Quiza ese permiso lo este usando otra app, pero no encuentro donde y tampoco información
Saludos y gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrijo el paquete

```
external_app_launcher
```

Inyecta permisos QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES

Para quienes lo usan si publican en play store van a tener que justificar y grabar un vídeo para eso. Y depende de eso Google play publicará la actualización. En mi caso tuve que quitar paquete.